# Como redimensionar imagens antes de realizar o upload?

Tags: php

Estou precisando redimensionar as imagens ao realizar o upload junto ao db, no entanto apesar de encontrar soluções eu não estou conseguindo incorporar no código.

```
<?php
include "conexao.php";

$titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
$arquivo = $_FILES['arquivo']['name'];
$categoria = $_POST['categoria'];


// Pasta onde o arquivo vai ser salvo
$_UP['pasta'] = 'uploads/';
// Tamanho máximo do arquivo (em Bytes)
$_UP['tamanho'] = 1024 * 1024 * 2; // 2Mb
// Array com as extensões permitidas
$_UP['extensoes'] = array('jpg', 'png', 'gif');
// Renomeia o arquivo? (Se true, o arquivo será salvo como .jpg e um    nome único)
$_UP['renomeia'] = true;
// Array com os tipos de erros de upload do PHP
$_UP['erros'][0] = 'Não houve erro';
$_UP['erros'][1] = 'O arquivo no upload é maior do que o limite do    PHP';
$_UP['erros'][2] = 'O arquivo ultrapassa o limite de tamanho    especifiado no HTML';
$_UP['erros'][3] = 'O upload do arquivo foi feito parcialmente';
$_UP['erros'][4] = 'Não foi feito o upload do arquivo';
// Verifica se houve algum erro com o upload. Se sim, exibe a mensagem    do erro
if ($_FILES['arquivo']['error'] != 0) {
die("Não foi possível fazer o upload, erro:" . $_UP['erros']   [$_FILES['arquivo']['error']]);
exit; // Para a execução do script
}
// Caso script chegue a esse ponto, não houve erro com o upload e o  PHP    pode continuar
// Faz a verificação da extensão do arquivo
@$extensao = strtolower(end(explode('.', $_FILES['arquivo'] ['name'])));
if (array_search($extensao, $_UP['extensoes']) === false) {
echo "Por favor, envie arquivos com as seguintes extensões: jpg, png     ou gif";
exit;
}
// Faz a verificação do tamanho do arquivo
if ($_UP['tamanho'] < $_FILES['arquivo']['size']) {
echo "O arquivo enviado é muito grande, envie arquivos de até 2Mb.";
exit;
}
// O arquivo passou em todas as verificações, hora de tentar movê-lo    para a pasta
// Primeiro verifica se deve trocar o nome do arquivo
if ($_UP['renomeia'] == true) {
// Cria um nome baseado no UNIX TIMESTAMP atual e com extensão .jpg
$nome_final = md5(time()).'.jpg';
} else {
// Mantém o nome original do arquivo
$nome_final = $_FILES['arquivo']['name'];
}

// Depois verifica se é possível mover o arquivo para a pasta  escolhida
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], $_UP['pasta'] .     $nome_final)) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO usuario(titulo, foto, categoria) VALUES   ('$titulo', '$nome_final', '$categoria')";
$query = $con->query($sql); /*= mysqli_query($sql, $cad_produto);*/

        if($query!=null){
            print "    <script>alert(\".\");window.location='../postar.php';</script>";
        }


 }

?>
```

Comment: qual erro você está tendo?

Comment: Neste código nenhum, o que desejo é adaptá-lo para poder redimensionar as imagens ao realizar o upload, no entanto não sei como fazer, eu encontrei esse tutorial mas ao tentar mesclar os dois o upload não é realizado. [https://www.linhadecomando.com/php/php-funcao-para-redimensionar-arquivos-de-foto]

Comment: Um começo: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.imagecopyresized.php

Answer (score -1):

Este [código](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12757005/php-resize-image-on-or-before-upload) pode ajudar:

```
    include("resize-class.php");

    // *** 1) Inicializar Imagem
    $resizeObj = new resize('sample.png');

    // *** 2) Redimensionar imagens (Opções: exato, retrato, paisagem, auto, crop)
    $resizeObj -> resizeImage(200, 200, 'crop');

    // *** 3) Salvar imagem
    $resizeObj -> saveImage('sample-resizeda.jpg', 1000);
```

**resize-class.php**

```
# ========================================================================#
   #  Requires : Requires PHP5, GD library.
   #  Usage Example:
   #                     include("resize_class.php");
   #                     $resizeObj = new resize('images/cars/large/input.jpg');
   #                     $resizeObj -> resizeImage(150, 100, 0);
   #                     $resizeObj -> saveImage('images/cars/large/output.jpg', 100);
   # ========================================================================#


        class resize
        {
            // *** Class variables
            private $image;
            private $width;
            private $height;
            private $imageResized;

            function __construct($fileName)
            {
                // *** Open up the file
                $this->image = $this->openImage($fileName);

                // *** Get width and height
                $this->width  = imagesx($this->image);
                $this->height = imagesy($this->image);
            }

            ## --------------------------------------------------------

            private function openImage($file)
            {
                // *** Get extension
                $extension = strtolower(strrchr($file, '.'));

                switch($extension)
                {
                    case '.jpg':
                    case '.jpeg':
                        $img = @imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
                        break;
                    case '.gif':
                        $img = @imagecreatefromgif($file);
                        break;
                    case '.png':
                        $img = @imagecreatefrompng($file);
                        break;
                    default:
                        $img = false;
                        break;
                }
                return $img;
            }

            ## --------------------------------------------------------

            public function resizeImage($newWidth, $newHeight, $option="auto")
            {
                // *** Get optimal width and height - based on $option
                $optionArray = $this->getDimensions($newWidth, $newHeight, $option);

                $optimalWidth  = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
                $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];


                // *** Resample - create image canvas of x, y size
                $this->imageResized = imagecreatetruecolor($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight);
                imagecopyresampled($this->imageResized, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $this->width, $this->height);


                // *** if option is 'crop', then crop too
                if ($option == 'crop') {
                    $this->crop($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $newWidth, $newHeight);
                }
            }

            ## --------------------------------------------------------

            private function getDimensions($newWidth, $newHeight, $option)
            {

               switch ($option)
                {
                    case 'exact':
                        $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                        $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                        break;
                    case 'portrait':
                        $optimalWidth = $this->getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight);
                        $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                        break;
                    case 'landscape':
                        $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                        $optimalHeight= $this->getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth);
                        break;
                    case 'auto':
                        $optionArray = $this->getSizeByAuto($newWidth, $newHeight);
                        $optimalWidth = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
                        $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];
                        break;
                    case 'crop':
                        $optionArray = $this->getOptimalCrop($newWidth, $newHeight);
                        $optimalWidth = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
                        $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];
                        break;
                }
                return array('optimalWidth' => $optimalWidth, 'optimalHeight' => $optimalHeight);
            }

            ## --------------------------------------------------------

            private function getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight)
            {
                $ratio = $this->width / $this->height;
                $newWidth = $newHeight * $ratio;
                return $newWidth;
            }

            private function getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth)
            {
                $ratio = $this->height / $this->width;
                $newHeight = $newWidth * $ratio;
                return $newHeight;
            }

            private function getSizeByAuto($newWidth, $newHeight)
            {
                if ($this->height < $this->width)
                // *** Image to be resized is wider (landscape)
                {
                    $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                    $optimalHeight= $this->getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth);
                }
                elseif ($this->height > $this->width)
                // *** Image to be resized is taller (portrait)
                {
                    $optimalWidth = $this->getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight);
                    $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                }
                else
                // *** Image to be resizerd is a square
                {
                    if ($newHeight < $newWidth) {
                        $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                        $optimalHeight= $this->getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth);
                    } else if ($newHeight > $newWidth) {
                        $optimalWidth = $this->getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight);
                        $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                    } else {
                        // *** Sqaure being resized to a square
                        $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                        $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                    }
                }

                return array('optimalWidth' => $optimalWidth, 'optimalHeight' => $optimalHeight);
            }

            ## --------------------------------------------------------

            private function getOptimalCrop($newWidth, $newHeight)
            {

                $heightRatio = $this->height / $newHeight;
                $widthRatio  = $this->width /  $newWidth;

                if ($heightRatio < $widthRatio) {
                    $optimalRatio = $heightRatio;
                } else {
                    $optimalRatio = $widthRatio;
                }

                $optimalHeight = $this->height / $optimalRatio;
                $optimalWidth  = $this->width  / $optimalRatio;

                return array('optimalWidth' => $optimalWidth, 'optimalHeight' => $optimalHeight);
            }

            ## --------------------------------------------------------

            private function crop($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $newWidth, $newHeight)
            {
                // *** Find center - this will be used for the crop
                $cropStartX = ( $optimalWidth / 2) - ( $newWidth /2 );
                $cropStartY = ( $optimalHeight/ 2) - ( $newHeight/2 );

                $crop = $this->imageResized;
                //imagedestroy($this->imageResized);

                // *** Now crop from center to exact requested size
                $this->imageResized = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth , $newHeight);
                imagecopyresampled($this->imageResized, $crop , 0, 0, $cropStartX, $cropStartY, $newWidth, $newHeight , $newWidth, $newHeight);
            }

            ## --------------------------------------------------------

            public function saveImage($savePath, $imageQuality="100")
            {
                // *** Get extension
                $extension = strrchr($savePath, '.');
                   $extension = strtolower($extension);

                switch($extension)
                {
                    case '.jpg':
                    case '.jpeg':
                        if (imagetypes() & IMG_JPG) {
                            imagejpeg($this->imageResized, $savePath, $imageQuality);
                        }
                        break;

                    case '.gif':
                        if (imagetypes() & IMG_GIF) {
                            imagegif($this->imageResized, $savePath);
                        }
                        break;

                    case '.png':
                        // *** Scale quality from 0-100 to 0-9
                        $scaleQuality = round(($imageQuality/100) * 9);

                        // *** Invert quality setting as 0 is best, not 9
                        $invertScaleQuality = 9 - $scaleQuality;

                        if (imagetypes() & IMG_PNG) {
                             imagepng($this->imageResized, $savePath, $invertScaleQuality);
                        }
                        break;

                    // ... etc

                    default:
                        // *** No extension - No save.
                        break;
                }

                imagedestroy($this->imageResized);
            }


            ## --------------------------------------------------------

        }
?>
```